Some NetBeans projects run with Xdebug but others won't
I am running NetBeans 12.6 with WAMP under Windows 11 and have one project (call it TVC) which is debugging OK. I added a second project (call it TLH). This gives me the  "waiting for connection" message. If both projects are loaded the TVC one debugs OK but the TLH one won't, even though the "running" message appears.
I completely cleared NetBeans, WAMP and the TLH project from my system and reinstalled them, the local domains and NetBeans (this time v21) but the situation is the same.
I then added two other projects. One of them worked with the debugger, the other didn't.
Could somebody suggest where I might look for a difference between the various projects that might cause the debugger to fail? As the TVC project debugs perfectly, it seems the problem lies either with the NetBeans project configuration or the project files.
What further information can I supply that would help resolve the issue?
